# Deploying Python app to Heroku: "Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution."

Tags: python, heroku, pip, setuptools, buildpack

Whenever I'm trying to push using the 'git push origin HEAD:master --force' command, I'm getting the following setuptools error (check out the screenshot): "Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution".

[image]

I thought it was related to the recent pip/setuptools update in official python buildpack.. so i made a fork of buildpack's repository and did a roll-back to the previous commits where old versions were used, but it didn't help. I tried to execute a 'purge-cache' command.. no luck. Then I tried to do a 'reset', change requirements.txt.. But it all just doesn't help to solve the problem. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally found the reason. I had some weird `pkg_resources.py` module sitting in the root directory. Have no idea what is it for and why it was there (it's like a long-time project, so I didn't participate in adding that module). But the thing is that after I removed that crap - everything works like a charm